# How can i use localStorage in a dark mode toggle?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, toggle, helper, darkmode

I am using the following javascript code to switch between dark mode and light mode through CSS themes and it works perfectly, but when I add the local.storage, the browser does not save the mode preferences. How can I do it?

HTML:

```
<button id="darkmode" type="button" onclick="toggleDark()">
<span id="night" class="material-icons">mode_night </span>
<span id="light" class="material-icons">light_mode</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
[data-theme="light"] {
--main-color: #dfdad8;
--sec-color: #202527;
--third-color: #6e6e65;
--one--color: #acf2be4d;
--two--color: #fdb8c052;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
 --main-color: #6e6e65;
 --sec-color: #f5f5f5;
 --third-color: #202527;
 --one--color: #acf2bd;
 --two--color: #fdb8c0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function toggleDark() {
  const container = document.body;
  const dataTheme = container.getAttribute("data-theme");
  let theme = localStorage.getItem("data-theme");

if (dataTheme === "light") {
  container.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
  document.getElementById("night").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("light").style.display = "none";
  localStorage.toggled("data-theme", "dark");

} else {

  container.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
  document.getElementById("night").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("light").style.display = "block";
  localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "light");
  }
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.toggled()` should throw an error unless you have added such a method yourself. Any errors in your dev tools console? Why use `toggled()` in one condition and the proper `setItem()` in the other?

Comment: I have already fixed this condition and I have tried both options, toggled() and setItem() and in no case the value of the "data-theme" is saved. And the console does not throw any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 issues:

-Your code disregards the saved value.

-localStorage.toggled is not a thing

```
const container = document.body;
if(localStorage.getItem("data-theme")){
container.setAttribute("data-theme",localStorage.getItem("data-theme")); 
toggleDark(1)
} 
//actually use the saved value

function toggleDark(r) {//this function is executed when switching from the current theme to the other
    const dataTheme = container.getAttribute("data-theme");
    let theme_switch;
    if(dataTheme === "light") {theme_switch = 1} else {theme_switch = 0}
    if(r){theme_switch = !theme_switch}//so the oppisite of the theme stored is used when calling this function 
if (theme_switch) {
  container.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
  document.getElementById("night").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("light").style.display = "none";
  localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "dark");
} else {
  container.setAttribute("data-theme", "light");
  document.getElementById("night").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("light").style.display = "block";
  localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "light");
  }
}
```

If the above code does not work then try the following steps.

open console and execute:
localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "dark");

then refresh the page and execute:
localStorage.getItem("data-theme")

if it returns null then there may be something blocking your cookies. try checking your settings.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias funciona perfectamente :D

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**

Change your localStorage.toggled to localStorage.set

```
if (dataTheme === "light") {
  container.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
  document.getElementById("night").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("light").style.display = "none";
  localStorage.setItem("data-theme", "dark");

}
```

Anyway you may want to check first if localStorage exists and if your "data-theme" exists. If "data-theme" doesn't exist you should set a default value.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("data-theme") === null) {
  //set default
}
```

**->**

I have created an example of your code in CodePen and it seems to be working just fine:
https://codepen.io/Hkrie/pen/ZEXEReq

If it still isn't working on your machine you may have disabled the localStorage or are using a browser without it. (a possible fix would be to use cookies instead -> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: There is no `localStorage.set()`. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @charkuetfk typo

Comment: I have already fixed this condition and I have tried both options, toggled() and setItem() and in no case the value of the "data-theme" is saved. And the console does not throw any error.

Comment: @JulenSanchez It seems to be working fine: https://codepen.io/Hkrie/pen/ZEXEReq

Comment: @Hkrie Yes, the button works fine, what doesn't work is the localStorage, when I move through the links of the web it doesn't save the preference.